# Include default export in Angular AOT build

Tags: angular, amcharts4

I'm using a map library that exports polygon definition as:

```
export default {
  ...
}
```

in various files like **world.ts** for example.

I then utilise the data in my Angular component using:

```
import mapData from '@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/world';
```

It all works well when running `ng serve` but the data does not simply pass through when the build has been run.

Upon reading the [limitations of AOT](https://github.com/UltimateAngular/aot-loader/wiki/Limitations-with-AoT), the default exports are not supported; though it has been rectified in Angular 9.

Is there some configuration in `angular.json` or a way I can import the data in the build? I run Angular 8.

Comment: Did you set `--build-optimizer=false` in your config as mentioned in the [AmCharts Angular Integration tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/integrations/using-angular2/)? This is required due to a bug in Angular, as outlined in [this issue](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1146).

Comment: Ah yes it works now. Has it been resolved in the Angular Ivy?

Comment: @xorspark and please post this as an answer so that I may accept it (for my particular case)

Comment: We haven't tested Angular Ivy, can't say for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `--build-optimizer=false` is set in your config as mentioned in AmCharts' [Angular Integration tutorial](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/integrations/using-angular2/). This is due to a bug in their build optmizer as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1146); [this comment](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1146#issuecomment-526386236) links to several similar complaints about the build-optimizer breaking third party code.